Automatic subtraction according to conditions in Google Sheets
how to make automatic subtraction vertically downwards according to conditions in Google Sheets



SKU
SKU BALANCE
ID CUST
CUST ORDER
DESIRE FORMULA




10100
100
115501
90
10


10100
100
115502
10
0









10036
100
115503
25
75


10036
100
115504
25
50


10036
100
115505
5
45









10040
100
115506
50
50


10040
100
115507
25
25


10040
100
115508
30
-5









10041
100
115519
50
DUPLICATES


10041
100
115519
50
DUPLICATES


10041
100
115519
50
DUPLICATES









10036
100
115520
45
0



https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJKWrmMXNtvNoVY7KiBSX-_b7yKPh6Ooa3gcnubqi3o/edit?gid=0#gid=0


Here's one generalized formula approach which you may adapt accordingly
Also the formula as of now does not deal with a scenario where lets say SKU 10041 has only 2 dupe ID CUST no.s and one distinct no. or so since no clarity is given on such a thing!
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,if(let(Λ,filter(C:C,A:A=Σ),counta(Λ)<>countunique(Λ)),"DUPLICATE",+filter(B:B,A:A=Σ)-sum(chooserows(filter(D:D,A:A=Σ),sequence(countif(A2:Σ,Σ))))))))


